# Django problem overriding all auth Signup forms

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Thanks in advance, i'm learning Django and can't figure how to override all auth forms. Quick explanation first, I have a custom user model

```
class PersoUser(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name="Email Adress", max_length=200, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(
    verbose_name="username", max_length=200, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="firstname", max_length=200)
last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="lastname", max_length=200)

date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name="birthday")
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

objects = PersoUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["date_of_birth", "username"]

....
```

and I would want to add date_of_birth field to my signup page, so I followed the official doc to override the specif form used by all auth SignupView https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#signup-allauth-account-forms-signupform

which leads to ( in Book_store/forms.py )

```
from all auth.account.forms import SignupForm from users. models import PersoUser



class PersoUserRegisterForm(SignupForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PersoUser
        fields = ["username", "email", "first_name",
                  "last_name", "date_of_birth",  "password1", "password2"]

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(PersoUserRegisterForm, self).save(request)

        # Add your processing here.

        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

- in my settings/base.py

  ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'Book_store.forms.PersoUserRegisterForm'}

My account/signup.html template just refers to {{form.as_p}} and it doesn't display the extra fields specified in PersouserRegisterForm just the default ones

I don't see what I'm missing, Thanks for reading

EDIT: And Signing up fail because it violates not-null constraint for date_of_birth

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the save method but not saving user with the date_of_birth field .

```
def save(self, request):
    user = super(PersoUserRegisterForm, self).save(request)
    user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: I'm going to test but could you tell me why I didn't have to do it when overidding forms.modelForm ( before using all auth sign up ) ?  user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

Comment: it's not working, it still displays default fields , i run this test : self.assertIsInstance(response.context.get("form"), PersoUserRegisterForm) and no error